# Laravel GuzzleHttp response empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I'm trying to retrieve the value of a URL but it returns a null response. Not sure what I'm doing wrong I've been trying to retrieve the value but I get an empty value. Below is my code

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/');

dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

When trying to dump the response I get the below response

[image]

When trying to read the `getBody()` of the response I get this output

[image]

I'm using guzzle "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.4"

Comment: maybe it is actually returning an empty body, what is the status code

Comment: If you visit the actual url its returning a json response and code is 200

Comment: What is in dd($response);

Comment: if you use `file_get_contents($url)` is it still empty?

Comment: @lagbox file_get_contents return the result I was expecting. But it's in a string format which is understandable. But what I would like to use is retrieving the value using guzzlehttp as there are possibilities that an authentication will be needed in this endpoint

Comment: yes i know, this was to test if there was any other issues, ruling out possible problems as guzzle can use different methods to get the content including curl if it is there

Comment: I understand. Not sure if there is something I need to check? Seems like I'm missing something in Guzzle implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found the solution to my problem. It's got nothing to do with

> $response->getBody()->getContents()

But the problem was the Endpoint/URL might require a user agent as part of the parameter of the url

my code I was able to retrieve the value using the code below

```
$url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/';
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    'verify' => false,
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => 'CUSTOM_AGENT_YOU_WANT' // THIS IS WHAT I ADDED TO MAKE IT WORK
    ]
]);

dd(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true));
```